# WordPress on IIS works except for image upload widget: Win 10 Pro

Tags: images, uploads

I installed latest wordpress on Windows 10 pro. When I upload images, it gives a generic error (An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later), momentarily flashes the image and vanishes. It does not show the image.

When I go to the upload folder it has the image there. Also, if I use the html tag on the blog, it shows the image alright. I tried to give everyone permission to the wp-content and the temporary folder but of no avail.

I looks like the upload widget is causing the issue. Any ideas where to look for?

Also, getting this error in debug:

```
[14-Nov-2020 23:15:22 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in C:\Tools\wordpress\wp-includes\post.php on line 6774
[14-Nov-2020 23:15:22 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in C:\Tools\wordpress\wp-includes\post.php on line 6858
```

Comment: That looks like you're somehow getting non-post objects into one of the $posts arrays. I've seen something similar with another plugin that updated a cache using the right type of object at the time but then that changed in a later WordPress. I'd guess your widget isn't compatible with the latest version of WordPress?

Comment: If you want to debug this then I'd dump out the $posts array at either of those lines and see what you've got without an ID, then try and work out where that came from.

Comment: I finally found that in the posts table in mySql there were many ids that were duplicates. This column is autonumber so I am not sure why they were showing as duplicates. It probably happened when I imported the blog from another system. Anyhow, I fixed all the duplicates and the problem is now gone.